confused about 4 quadrant arctan function after complex integration
You can obtain the following real indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{a(u-b)du}{u^2+a^2}=a\log(\sqrt{u^2+a^2})-b\arctan(\frac{u}{a})$$
on the other hand, the integrand can be expressed as the real part of a complex
$$\int \frac{a(u-b)du}{u^2+a^2}=\Re{ \int \frac{(-b+ja)(a-ju)du}{(a+ju)(a-ju)} }
=\Re{ \int (a+jb)\frac{jdu}{a+ju} }=\Re{(a+jb)\log(a+ju)}$$
$$=a\log(\sqrt{u^2+a^2})-b\arctan2(u,a)$$
where $j$ is the unit imaginary and the function $\arctan2(y,x)=\arg(x+jy)$ is the .4-quadrant inverse tangent function
As can be seen, only the arctangent function is altered into 4-quadrant. There is something I am not considering in the complex integration.

The two arctangent functions do agree on the half-plane where $0 < u$, right...? Or is that not the question?

@AndrewD.Hwang In fact for $a>0$ they produce the same result. but the question is that complex integration results in the argument of a complex value that is different from a simple arctan.

I see. <> Two other thoughts that may or may not help: (i) In any region where both formulas make sense (such as the half plane where $u < 0$, or if $a < 0$), they locally differ by a constant. (ii) If we view $a$ and $b$ as real parameters, we cannot "move continuously" from positive to negative values of $a$.

Do it the standard way
$$\frac{u-b}{a^2+u^2}=\frac{1}{2}\  \left(\frac{1}{u-i a}+\frac{1}{u+i a}\right)-\frac{b}{2 i a}\  \left(\frac{1}{u-i a}-\frac{1}{u+i a}\right)$$
Map the integral operator into the sum
$$\text{res}=\frac{1}{2} (\int \text{$\#$1} \, du\&)\text{/@}\left(\frac{1}{u-i a}+\frac{1}{u+i a}\right)-\frac{b}{2 i a} \ (\int \text{$\#$1} \, du\&)\text{/@}\left(\frac{1}{u-i a}-\frac{1}{u+i a}\right)$$
The result are 4 log terms, open to find a common cut in the complex plane
$$\frac{i b}{2 a}\cdot (\log (u-i a)-\log (u+i a))+\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\log (u-i a)+\log (u+i a))$$
The derivative works indepently of the choice of the path of integration
$$\frac{\partial \text{res}}{\partial u}=\frac{u-b}{a^2+u^2}$$
If one does not specify domains, there are identities on the positive reals
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\log \left(1-\frac{i u}{a}\right)-\log \left(1+\frac{i u}{a}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2} i \log \left(\frac{a+i u}{a-i u}\right)$$

Residue theorem often deals with definite integrals with infinite bounds, Unless using a change of variable... Can you edit your answer for $\int_{u_1}^{u_2} \frac{a(u-b)du}{u^2+a^2}$?
